# What is the best way to make sure PendingIntents get the correct action?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

In my app, I have a lot of alarms, notifications and widgets, all of which require PendingIntents.
Having all of these items run along side each other, I was wandering what is the best way to make sure the PendingIntents will not get mixed together.

After reading [PendingIntent's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), and this part specifically:

> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something that is different about them to associate them with different PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by Intent.filterEquals, or different request code integers supplied to getActivity...

I thought of the following solution: having a class that generates request codes by keeping the current one in shared prefs, and everytime a request code is needed, it will progress the last value, return it and store it.
Something like:

```
private static final String PREF_PREV_UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE = "UniquePendingIntentRequestCodeGenerator.PREF_PREV_UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE";

private static final int INITIAL_UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE = 10000;

public static int generateUniqueRequestCode () {

    //get new request code and store
    int prevRequestCode = SharedPrefsManager.getInstance().getPref(SharedPrefsManager.PREF_NAME_GLOBAL_PREFS, PREF_PREV_UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE , INITIAL_UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE);
    int newRequestCode = prevRequestCode + 1;

    //save for general count
    SharedPrefsManager.getInstance().setPref(SharedPrefsManager.PREF_NAME_GLOBAL_PREFS, PREF_PREV_UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE , newRequestCode);

    return newRequestCode;
}
```

What do you think about this solution? Do you have a better one in mind?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application and what you are using the `PendingIntent`s for. If, for example, each `PendingIntent` has a unique ACTION then you don't need to have unique request codes.

However, if the request code is the only thing that you can make unique, then the solution you have suggested sounds just fine.